# AU shows me as not logged in while I'm logged in

Tags: bug, login

I'm using Firefox 24.6 ESR (usually in the form of Tor Browser) to access several SE sites. Usually I log in at [Tor.SE](https://tor.stackexchange.com/) and then move to other sites. AskUbuntu shows a unique behaviour among other SE sites. So I visit the site and at some point decide to log in. So I click on [the Login link](https://askubuntu.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2F) and choose the correct link there. Now AU redirects me to the original page and *does not* show me as logged in. Only when I manually visit https://askubuntu.com/users/login I see the head and all other site visits are done as a logged in user. What can be the reason for this and how can this be resolved?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled? Are you blocking any of SE's CDNs?

Comment: Your login url is different than the one I get. Mine uses https for the url, and http for the redirect. This means when I browse the site my connection isn't secure, but that's how AskUbuntu does it for me. After I can switch manually to https. Maybe try that? Link = https://askubuntu.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2faskubuntu.com%2f

Comment: Are you using Tor Browser Bundle or Noscript by any chance? Noscript interferes with login occasionally  and always with auto login, even if scripts are globally allowed. You might want to take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help

Comment: @Cammy_the_block - note Noscript works brilliantly, you just need to allow 'askubuntu.com', 'sstatic.net' and 'ajax.googleapis.com'

Comment: Are you sure, because auto login didn't work for me (even with scripts globally allowed) until I disabled Noscript. Normal login did, given that all the login page was temporarily allowed.

Comment: @unorthodoxgrammar I'm using [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) which tries to load SE urls via HTTPS.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Yes, usually I use TBB. However I see this behaviour only on AU. It works on Tor.SE without any issues. Thatswhy I assume it is a 'AU problem'.